# Mono can't cast TypeA to TypeA

Tags: c#, linux, macos, plugins, mono

I'm creating a plugin framework with C#. The main requirements of the framework is to load, unload and update plugins at runtime.

To accomplish this I've been creating AppDomains and loading the plugin assemblies into the AppDomains.

Everything works fine on Microsoft .NET on windows but the plugins do not work on mono running on mac or linux.

When trying to start a plugin I get an exception like this:

Cannot cast argument 0 of type 'System.Func`1[[API.Network.NodeType, API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' to type 'System.Func`1[[API.Network.NodeType, API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

This is caused because each plugin has it's own copy of the API.dll assembly, and though the assembly is an identical copy, mono doesn't see the Types as being the same.

How can I get the plugin to load the API.dll from the main application's directory? Or, alternatively, how can I get mono to see the Types as being the same?

Answer (score 1):

Well to find answer to your question I created a simple plugin system and tested it on mono 3.2.3 under the Windows successfully (unfortunately I can't make test on Linux now, maybe tomorrow). My code:

**SDK.dll**

```
using System;

namespace SDK
{
    public interface IPlugin
    {
        void SomeMethod();

        SomeSDKType GetSDKType();

    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SDK
{
    [Serializable]
    public class StringEventArgs : EventArgs
    {

        public string Message { get; set; }

    }

    public class SomeSDKType : MarshalByRefObject
    {

        public event EventHandler<StringEventArgs> SDKEvent;

        public Action SDKDelegate;

        public void RiseSDKEvent(string message)
        {
            var handler = SDKEvent;
            if (handler != null) SDKEvent(this, new StringEventArgs { Message = message });
        }

        public Dictionary<int, string> GetDictionary()
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<int, string> ();
            dict.Add(1, "One");
            dict.Add(2, "Two");
            return dict;
        }

    }
}
```

**Plugin.dll**

```
using System;
using SDK;

namespace Plugin
{
    public class Plugin : MarshalByRefObject, IPlugin
    {
        public Plugin()
        {
        }

        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod");
        }

        public SomeSDKType GetSDKType()
        {
            var obj = new SomeSDKType();
            obj.SDKDelegate = () => Console.WriteLine("Delegate called from {0}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

**Hosting program**

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using SDK;

namespace AppDomains
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Plugin domain"); // Domain for plugins
            domain.Load(typeof(IPlugin).Assembly.FullName); // Load assembly containing plugin interface to domain 

            var currentPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            var pluginPath = Path.Combine(currentPath, "Plugins");
            var pluginFiles = Directory.GetFiles(pluginPath, "*.dll");
            foreach (var pluginFile in pluginFiles) // Foreach dll in Plugins directory
            {
                var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(pluginFile);
                foreach (var exportedType in asm.GetExportedTypes())
                {
                    if (!typeof(IPlugin).IsAssignableFrom(exportedType)) continue; // Check if exportedType implement IPlugin interface
                    domain.Load(asm.FullName); // If so load this dll into domain
                    var plugin = (IPlugin)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(asm.FullName, exportedType.FullName); // Create plugin instance
                    plugin.SomeMethod(); // Call plugins methods
                    var obj = plugin.GetSDKType();
                    obj.SDKDelegate();
                    var dict = obj.GetDictionary();
                    foreach (var pair in dict)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
                    }
                    obj.SDKEvent += obj_SDKEvent;
                    obj.RiseSDKEvent(string.Format("Argument from domain {0}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName));
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void obj_SDKEvent(object sender, StringEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Received event in {0}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="Plugins"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Some explanation to code. I created SDK dll with plugin interface. All plugins and host app must reference to it. Plugins must be provided without SDK dll because host app already contains it. They puts into the **Plugins** directory in the host application directory (ie if app path = *c:\MyApp* the plugins are in *c:\MyApp\Plugins*) so to provide CLR (or mono) opportunity to find plugin assemplies I also created App.config file with probing element.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your solution still wouldn't work because "domain.Load(typeof(IPlugin).Assembly.FullName);" will still load the plugin's copy of SDK.dll and not the host application's copy (FullName is an assembly name and not a filename).

My current code already can create instances of the plugin. The problem occurs when trying to work with Types defined in the API (your SDK.dll) that need to pass between AppDomains.

Comment: That’s strange. In my example I have only one copy of the SDK.dll (I have AppDomains.exe and SDK.dll assemblies in application root and Plugin.dll in app root\Plugins). When you use domain.Load()each domain loads its own copy of the assembly and search it in GAC and the application directory by full name (only mscorelib.dll shared between domains). Therefore in my example the application domain and the plugin domain loads the same SDK.dll.

Comment: I updated my answer to provide more complicated example. There are some possible issues may occur when you use cross domain interaction. First make sure that all assemblies referenced by your plugins lie in GAC or application directory. Second all your objects crossing app domain must be derived from MarshalByRefObject (or marked as [Serializable]). Also you can’t create instance of delegate and array with domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap().

Comment: Ah, I see you're advocating setting the appdomain to load all it's references from the host's directory. Which works to a point, it gets problematic when a plugin has references though :/ Shadow copying any dependencies is going to get real messy real fast.

Comment: By the way why you don't use microsoft MEF? Is it not work on mono?

Comment: I think using only one SDK dll for the host and plugins is a good practice. Providing each plugin with its own copy of the SDK assembly can bring to security problems. Maybe you can provide a piece of your problematic code to make your question clearer?